# ajax call back, how to pass messages and data?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Hi I am learning a bit of ajax and a bit confused.

It all works but not 100% sure why? I have the script below of how its structured. What I want to know is how the success: function(result) works. In my php I have the echo for 1 or 0 but I would like to include more info in my php ie the correct message.

My javascript is.

```
$("#username1").blur(function(){

 var username1 = $('#username1').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/gonnabook/check_username_availability",
    data:  'username1='+ username1,
    success: function(result){
    if(result == 1){
        alert("true");
        }
    else{
        alert("false");
        }
   }
});
```

php is

```
function check_username_availability(){

        $check_this = $this->input->post('username1');  
        $data = $this->tank_auth->is_username_available($check_this);
        // the above code does all the query and results in the data
        if($data){
              echo 1;
             //ideally I would like to add a message here ie This is not available
        }else{
            echo 0;

        }
 }
```

So far my understanding is the echo 1 in the php is what the success function in the javascript receives. But how would include a message in the php? Can one do it via an array or something and then the result is result.check or something like that?
The main point is what is the correlation of the result in the javascript and echo of the php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to, instead of echoing `0` or `1` would be to echo a JSON object... Try this...

**PHP**

```
function check_username_availability(){

        //This array will hold the data we return to JS- as many items as you want
        $result=array();  

        $check_this = $this->input->post('username1');  
        $data = $this->tank_auth->is_username_available($check_this);
        // the above code does all the query and results in the data
        if($data){
             $result['success']=1;
             $result['message']='This is a random message';
             $result['data']=data; //You can even return the retrieved data
        }else{
             $result['success']=0;

        }
        die(json_encode($result)); //Encode the array into JSON and echo the string
 }
```

**JS**

```
$("#username1").blur(function(){
  var username1 = $('#username1').val();
  $.post(
        "http://localhost/gonnabook/check_username_availability", 
        {'username1': username1},
        function(result){
            if (result.success==1){
                alert('success: ' + result.message);
            } else {
                alert('error');
            }
        }, 
        'json'  //Tell JS we expect JSON in return
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, makes total sense now. And it works better now. Much appreciated.

Comment: Terrific. Happy coding my friend!

Answer (score 0):

it is this:

server-side(php) echoes and ajax listens this in success function

simple:

```
in php: echo "1"  ==> in ajax: success will get this 1 as result argument
```

you can pass anything you want.. array, list, dict, json...

here you can read with real examples what happens in the background when you work with ajax
https://web.archive.org/web/20140203201657/http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I have have learnt something new for Friday.

Answer (score 0):

What you usually do in your PHP script is to return your data serialized as a JSON string. This object then can be used in the success callback of the ajax call

**php script**:

```
function check_username_availability(){

 //do something fancy

 //create your JSON return
 var $data = array("foo" => "bar","bar" => "foo");
 echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**client**:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "http://localhost/gonnabook/check_username_availability",
 data:  'username1='+ username1,
 success: function(data){
  console.log(data['foo'] + ' ' + data['bar']); //echos "bar foo"
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I appreciate it and it helped. Have a good weekend.